# 1990 Suburban exhaust system replacement

Tags: chevrolet, exhaust, suburban

I recently purchased a 1990 Suburban - and it has a Chevy 350. The exhaust merges and exits on the left side.

I am unable to locate a replacement which is a direct fit. Also, almost all y-pipes online merge on the right.

Anyone has any experience with this - or knows a cross reference with another model?

**Update** - based on accepted answer - found the rest of the part numbers on the WALKER website

[image]

Comment: A 30-year-old vehicle with a non-standard exhaust system suggests to me that the previous owner(s) extemporized a repair with non-stock parts. Unless you're willing to buy an entire replacement system (all the way forward to the exhaust manifold, say), you might find a muffler shop that'll work with and repair what's already in place

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica That may be the truth. I am willing to replace everything but I can't find a direct fit for the burb

Comment: Are you looking under the "V" series Suburban (ie: V1500)? The WALKER 40317 Y Pipe drops on the left side.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Looks like V1500 is what I need since I have a 4x4. I think you re on it

Comment: I was thinking the transfer case drops on the right side, which would preclude the y-pipe coming down on that side. I wasn't sure what designation it would be, since GM usually calls the 4x4 a "K" series. I'd double check that and see, because "V" is new to me WRT any of the GM trucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking under the "V" series Suburban (ie: V1500), the WALKER 40317 Y Pipe drops on the left side. It is probably what you'd need for a 4x4. If memory serves me correctly, the front drive shaft of the transfer case drops on the right side, so they had to route it down the left side. Usually, GM used the "K" designation for 4x4's, so the V is tossing me around a little bit. I would suggest you ensure this is the part you need for your truck before purchase.

On how to find other parts you might need ... you just have to look. Online searches are probably the best. Now that you might have the a better designation for your Suburban, you might be able to find it easier. Secondarily, you should consider just taking it to a shop and having them build one for you or find the parts for you. It'd be done right and you wouldn't have to worry about the outcome.

If you're still heck-bent on doing it yourself, a resource I use is rockauto.com (no affiliation). They have a *very* extensive parts list, which means you can pick and choose. If you find what you need there, you can take the part numbers and shop it wherever you need to to find the parts.

Comment: Thank you - i found all the rest of system on the WALKER website.

Comment: @EdvBeq - That's awesome! If you want to give us an update, check out our chat room called [The Pitstop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/340/the-pitstop). We can talk freely over there.